# No non-missing arguments to min and max

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm using R to plot some coordinates on a map, using the the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

smalloperations <- read.csv("S:/smalloperations.csv", na.strings=c("","NA"))

lon <- c(smalloperations$target.longitude)
lat <- c(smalloperations$target.latitude)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon,lat))

# getting the map
mapgilbert <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(df$lon), lat = mean(df$lat)), 
zoom = 1, maptype = "satellite", scale = 2)

# plotting the map with some points on it
ggmap(mapgilbert) +
geom_point(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = "red", alpha = 0.8), size 
= 5, shape = 21) +
guides(fill=FALSE, alpha=FALSE, size=FALSE)
```

When I run this code I get this warning:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>   2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
>   3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>   4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Then the code displays the coordinates but with no map in the background. I have looked around and this error has occurred for other people but the solutions I saw don't seem to be suitable for my specific problem.
I am using a smaller, cleaned version of [this dataset from kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/usaf/world-war-ii) that has no nulls or NA in the target longitudes and latitudes that I'm using and there are no NA's at all in it.

My data structure:

```
'data.frame':   13 obs. of  20 variables:
$ mission.id                 : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ mission.date               : Factor w/ 1 level "15/08/1943": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 ...
$ theater.of.operations      : Factor w/ 4 levels "CBI","ETO","MTO",..: 3 4 
3 3 4 4 4 4 3 3 ...
$ country                    : Factor w/ 2 levels "GREAT BRITAIN",..: 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ air.force                  : Factor w/ 4 levels "10 AF","12 AF",..: 2 3 2 
2 3 3 3 3 2 2 ...
$ aircraft.series            : Factor w/ 4 levels "A36","B17","B24",..: 1 3 
1 1 3 3 3 2 1 1 ...
$ mission.type               : Factor w/ 4 levels "OBJECTIVE BOMBING",..: 4 
1 4 4 1 1 3 1 4 4 ...
$ takeoff.base               : Factor w/ 2 levels "PONTE OLIVO AIRFIELD",..: 
1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
$ takeoff.location           : Factor w/ 2 levels "SICILY","UNKNOWN": 1 2 1 
1 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
$ target.id                  : Factor w/ 6 levels "16140","3735",..: 4 6 5 1 
6 6 6 6 3 1 ...
$ target.country             : Factor w/ 5 levels "BURMA","GERMANY",..: 3 4 
3 3 5 4 4 4 3 3 ...
$ target.city.or.area        : Factor w/ 10 levels "BERLIN","COSENZA",..: 10 
6 2 3 5 4 8 8 9 3 ...
$ target.type                : Factor w/ 5 levels "AIRDROME","CITY AREA",..: 
4 3 4 4 5 4 4 1 4 4 ...
$ target.industry            : Factor w/ 3 levels "ARMAMENT AND ORDNANCE 
PLANTS",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 ...
$ target.priority            : int  9 1 9 9 1 1 1 1 9 9 ...
$ target.latitude            : num  38.22 -7.17 39.27 38.43 -1.12 ...
$ target.longitude           : num  15.4 147 16.2 15.9 103.9 ...
$ altitude..hundreds.of.feet.: int  139 44 139 139 60 35 70 40 139 139 ...
$ source.id                  : Factor w/ 9 levels "11287","11326",..: 9 8 9 
9 3 7 1 2 9 9 ...
$ bomb.type                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "HIGH EXPLOSIVES",..: 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: What line throws the error? The code doesn't involve either `min` or `max` explicitly.

Comment: I get the error after the last four lines, yeah I was thinking maybe I have to include them somewhere but I don't know where I would do that.

Comment: Your question is so far from being a [mcve] that it is hard to say anything, really. Some function (and you haven't specified which, exactly) doesn't like some input that you feed it (and we don't know what the input is). Should we just guess what the problem is?

Comment: Reading this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248 .

Comment: Since you aren't showing us your data - at least show the structure of your dataframe

    `str(df)`

then setup your data.frame in a more appropriate manner e.g.,

    `df <- data.frame(lon = smalloperations$target.longitude, 
                     lat = smalloperations$target.latitude)`
See if there is a different data structure 


Any `NULL` values in your `smalloperations` data? If so you need to use `mean(df$lon, na.rm=T)`. Or share your data and someone can likely address the question explicitly.

Comment: I added more information there and I included my data structure. Because of the amount of columns, when I try to show my data it becomes a bit of a mess but there's no NA's or NULL values in it, I replaced those with UNKNOWNS or used the mean to fill them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zoom is an integer from 3-20 http://stat405.had.co.nz/ggmap.pdf you are using 1

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, and hence should be added as a comment.

Comment: But if there are NAs in the data then it explains why there is no map. Kind of a chicken/egg thing, no?

Comment: I'm just voicing SO policy. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer especially the part about answering well-asked questions. Your answer was flagged in the review stack as "not an answer" and I just thought to inform you. I didn't make the policies here ;-)

Comment: ah - makes sense. changed up the answer.

Answer (score -1):

There is no reproducible answer so I cant be sure. But there (probably) a solution in the hablar package. mean in R does not work well with NA, Inf. Adding the s function on lat and lon gives you:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(hablar)

smalloperations <- read.csv("S:/smalloperations.csv", na.strings=c("","NA"))

lon <- c(smalloperations$target.longitude)
lat <- c(smalloperations$target.latitude)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon,lat))

# getting the map
mapgilbert <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(s(df$lon)), lat = mean(s(df$lat))), 
zoom = 1, maptype = "satellite", scale = 2)

# plotting the map with some points on it
ggmap(mapgilbert) +
geom_point(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = "red", alpha = 0.8), size 
= 5, shape = 21) +
guides(fill=FALSE, alpha=FALSE, size=FALSE)
```